# angular.js: how to reverse orderBy using '-' ?

Tags: angularjs

I am doing the angular tutorial step 4.

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04.

I don't understand how to implement this:

Reverse the sort order by adding a - symbol before the sorting value:

```
 <option value="-age">Oldest</option>
```

Comment: just add this option to the select element as a child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since age is a numerical value, all they are saying that you can reverse the sorting order by making the value of `orderProp` as negative `age`.

The docs are simply saying to hard code in another option tag, if you want to sort numerical value (the age in this case) in reverse:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
    <option value="age">Newest</option>
    <option value="-age">Oldest</option>
</select>
```

You could make this dynamic, which is much more advanced, however with the way this specific example is setup it is not user friendly.

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised that options can be hard coded into a databound select element without being removed by the binding logic and even affect the datamodel even though they were not generated by it

Comment: Aha. I thought I could *replace* `<option value="age">Newest</option>` with <option value="-age">Oldest</option>, but that doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: @pauld.waite Yeah I am not a big fan of sorting by `select`>`option` elements. It is much easier to do so through table header links. [See documentation example here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy)